# keystroke loss in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, keyboard

working in the latest version of Ubuntu, with all updates installed, I frequently have the problem of keystrokes being lost. I have that at least several times per sentence I type in any program (also when I'm typing this text).
I have ubuntu installed on a Toshiba Satellite L670.
I have this problem since months but it got worse to the level that it is not workable anymore.
Can somebody please help ?
thanks,
Dirk

Comment: If it is gradually getting worse, it may well be hardware failure. Please give more detail on where, when and which keystrokes are lost.

Answer (score 0):

can you try it with a regular keyboard?

if it persists with a regular keyboard its a software issue and I have no clue

but if its just that keyboard well then you need a new keyboard. I recommend a mechanical one since it will last and give you tactile feed back for many years to come.

Comment: I tried the laptops keyboard under windows 7 (since I have dual boot) but don't experience that problem. Also I connected an external keyboard to the laptop under Ubuntu but the problem persist.

Comment: ok check the keyboard settings on ubuntu make sure its the correct layout and what not. after that I'm sorry but I have no clue what your problem is sorry.